# Too Many Arguments when using IF google sheet

Tags: spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I want to implement this formula in Google sheet and I'm getting the error for too many ifs. Any help?

```
=IF(I2="win",SUM(J2*G2),IF(I2="loss",SUM(J2*-1),IF(I2="push",J2),IF(I2 = "half win",SUM(J2/2)*G2),IF(I2 = "half loss", SUM((J2/2)/2)*-1)))
```

Comment: You may want to check out the IFS function: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145

Answer (score 0):

This will work as desired:

```
=IFS(I2="win";SUMA(J2*G2);I2="loss";SUMA(J2*-1);I2="push";J2;I2 = "half win";SUMA(J2/2)*G2;I2 = "half loss"; SUMA((J2/2)/2)*-1)
```

But there is one hatch, You need to check wheter , shall not be replaced by ; and SUMA shall not be SUM. The script works in national settings of GoogleSpreadsheets to PL, where certain functions names and chars were changed. This can be tricky if You are not in country where native language is English.